# How to disable sticky edges in Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

I'm running Lubuntu 1604. There are easy options for ubuntu to disable sticky edges between screens; however I cant find something for LXDE running on Lubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use Lubuntu 16.04, you should have a program called `Openbox Configuration Manager` accessible from Menu > Preferences.

Here's a screenshot of the possibilities. Maybe something there will help:

[image: Resistance]

I don't have more than just the one screen and so can't say for sure.

Comment: Thanks @DK Bose , however I looked for something in these menus and wasn't looky.